# Regular Expression for Thousand Separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regular expression to validate input on key press.
The problem with regular expression is its allowing multiple comma to be enter in sequence .
Below is regular expression

```
"^\\-?\\d*(\,\\d{0,3})*(\\.\\d{0,2}?)?$"
```

Its allowing user to enter value like 100,,,,, which I want to stop.Match should be 123,000.00

In my case I want to allow user to type 100,
Input can end with comma as I am validating input on Keypress so It should allow 100,  (end with comma)

Comment: What should be matched"?

Comment: Please update question with code you have tried.

Comment: Match should be 111,000 .It shhould not allow user to enter 111,,,,000

Comment: Tried using `input type="number"`?

Comment: @guest271314 2  can't use it due to design limitation

Comment: are you including the decimals?

Comment: @JanLeeYu Yes Match  : 11,000,000.00    Should Not match -,  or 100,,, 
Should Allow 100,

Comment: you mean 100, is okay?

Comment: Yes , As I want to remove , at the end on blur. Its all problem is bcz need to do validation on Keypress

Answer (score 1):

You are getting multiple commas in sequence because of this line `(\,\\d{0,3})*`. Here you are saying to match 3 or no digits and commas 0 or more times. `,,,` means 1 comma and 0 digit 3 times. 
You can try this one to fix your problem: `^-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:[,.](?:\d{1,2})?)?$`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have modified it as per my need like ^-?(\d*)(,\d{1,3})*[,]?([.]\d{0,2})?$ Only issue its matching 123,.00 which should not ..any suggestion

Comment: Try this one: `^-?(\d*)(,\d{1,3})*(?:[,]|([.]\d{0,2}))?$`

Comment: If I will not write like this It will not match 123343 ,which is valid

Comment: which one is final , m confused now

Comment: The one in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110476/discussion-between-vivek-panday-and-sehrob).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

`^-?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?$`

This will match the one with check mark

```
100,000 √
100,,, 
100     √
100,    √
,100
100.00
```

This is another one because I dont get what you mean in the comment :

`^-?\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?$`

will match

```
100,000 √
100,,, 
100     √
100,    
,100
100.00  √
```

Though this will still match `1000,00`

Comment: Not match for -12323, ,but its should as per my need

Comment: Should not match 888,888888888888 I am using ^-?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?$

Answer (score 0):

If you not restrict the amount of number after the decimal point (ex: 2), you can try this regex `^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?$`